# Measurement of frequency deviation in FM signals

Tags: frequency-spectrum

Is there any way to measure frequency deviation in a recorded frequency modulated time domain data? The little research i have done on net mostly concerns with frequency deviation measurement using spectrum analyzer in real time i.e. data continuously​ received on spectrum analyzer​ while measuring deviation in carrier frequency.
If i record FM data using some digitizer and i know the carrier frequency, is it possible to measure frequency deviation using some fft technique on recorded data offline?

Thanks

Comment: You can do demodulation of pre-recorded FM signals, but, in my opinion, you'd better use a software implementation of all-digital phase locked loop in your solution rather than fft analyzers

Comment: @V.V.T I fully agree, the FFT is simply the wrong tool here. I'd ask you to write that as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: I would rather not make haste with prompts: maybe the OP is going to use the idea for a student research project.